# list all tasks based on groupings

Tags: vsto, ms-project

is there a way where i can list the tasks as shown if grouping is implemented?
Like for example, I used Group1 where it is grouped by Text1 then Text2. Using vsto, I want to have a list where I can get the exact hierarchical of the tasks with the computed % of completion.

thanks,
Gilbert

Comment: Way back in 2004, [Rod Gill](https://www.project-systems.co.nz/) chimed in on [a similar question](https://www.office-forums.com/threads/parse-current-views-tasks-and-group-headings-with-vba.1605054/) and said, "I don't think you can read group headings. The best you can do is export to Excel, then sort and subtotal there." It doesn't appear that anything has changed since then.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, then use VSTO to create a view that applies your Group/Filter combo. Then do a select all, and you can do whatever you want with the contents.

Comment: I would need to transfer the data to excel, exactly the way ms project is showing all tasks when grouped.

Comment: So, if you build the view like I suggested, I believe you can do a "Select All", then copy that directly to Excel. Should copy the colors, indents and everything.